# Does JTA wrap native sql-query into a transaction on low-level?

Tags: java, jta

I have a question about JTA. If we write the following:

```
@Resource UserTransaction userTransaction;
public void updateData() {
    // Start a transaction.
    userTransaction.begin();
    // ...
    // Perform transactional operations on data
    // Commit the transaction.
    userTransaction.commit();
}
```

will an sql-query generated by the operations on data be wrapped into a transaction like

```
BEGIN
--some sql-query
COMMIT
```

Comment: Not quite so simple - it depends on the JTA _implementation_. It will be wrapped into some sort of transaction, quite possibly an [Open XA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X/Open_XA) transaction.

Comment: So, it's possible to be implemented without low-level transaction, right?

Comment: A _some_ point _something_ is going to have to carry out a low-level transaction. It just might not look quite like that.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Let me ask does spring implementation of Transactions use JTA as an underlying API? Or it's implemented in its own way. I mean, when we mark a method with `@Transactional`

Comment: You are going through abstraction after abstraction without _understanding_. Spring transactions are **another** layer over a transaction api - an aspect orientated one. It uses a [`PlatformTransactionManager`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.1.2.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/support/AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.html) to implement the transactions. The very, very basic implementation is the `DataSourceTransactionManager`, which doesn't use JTA at all.